# Does mailinator provide a free STMP server like gmail or yahoo?

Tags: java, email, smtp, mailinator

I want a free SMTP server via which I can send emails using Java Email API.
I would have used google or yahoo but they all show the original recipient in the *from:* section(**which has my name in it**).

I tried creating a gmail id using some generic name like myxyzapp@gmail.com but Google and Yahoo don't allow creation of email ids without mobile number(**And I don't want to give this number**).

So I ran to mailinator which is awesome for creating temporary email ids but in the end it is the SMTP services that I am interested in, not email IDs.

Is there any free SMTP configuration for sending emails via Mailinator or any other SMTP server service provider ?

Comment: [FAQ](https://www.mailinator.com/faq.jsp) says *You cannot SEND from Mailinator - it is a receive-only service*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of smtp providers who provide free accounts, but these are shared servers which a lot of users use to send their mail, so there is a small chance these servers might be blacklisted due to spamming by free users and these free accounts have high restrictions placed on them as well. If this risk is not an issue for you I recommend , [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/free/) or [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com/pricing) which provide free but limited accounts.

Comment: I used sendgrid. It's beautiful.